# Aggregate data in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm looking for a dead simple example on how to use `aggregate` and calculate means in R.

Say, I have the following data frame:

```
A      B
100    85
200    95
300    110
400    105
```

And I want to calculate the mean values for some ranges with the following result:

```
RANGE         MEAN
100-200       90
300-400       107.5
```

How would I go about doing this, `cast()` or `aggregate()`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What variable do you want to aggregate on (What do you mean by "some ranges")?

Comment: Oh, forgot to change the heading for the second table - fixed now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is named "x":

```
aggregate(x$B, list(cut(x$A, breaks=c(0, 200, 400))), mean)
#     Group.1     x
# 1   (0,200]  90.0
# 2 (200,400] 107.5
```

---

With "data.table", you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(x)[, .(RANGE = mean(B)), by = .(MEAN = cut(A, c(0, 200, 400)))]
#         MEAN RANGE
# 1:   (0,200]  90.0
# 2: (200,400] 107.5
```

Comment: For nicer looking output: `aggregate(list(mean = df$B), list(range = cut(df$A, breaks=c(0, 200, 400))), mean)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a basic example of `aggregate` usage.

```
> foo = data.frame(A=c(100,200,300,400),B=c(85,95,110,105))
> aggregate(foo$B,by=list(foo$A<250),FUN=mean)
  Group.1     B
1   FALSE 107.5
2    TRUE  90.0
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or the same with `cut` and `tapply`

```
 foo <- data.frame(A=c(100,200,300,400),B=c(85,95,110,105))
 tapply(foo$B, cut(foo$A, breaks=seq(0, 400, 200)), mean)
  (0,200] (200,400] 
     90.0     107.5
```