# R Table data with a grouping command

Tags: r, frequency

This seems like a very simple problem, but I can't seem to sort it out. I have sought help from this forum, with the below topics being close, but don't seem to do exactly what I need. I have count data over several years. I want to obtain frequencies of the count value by year. It seems I need a table function with a grouping option, but I haven't found the proper syntax.

```
Data:
          count year
    1        15 1957
    2         6 1957
    3        23 1957
    4        23 1957
    5         2 1957
    6        28 1980
    7        15 1980
    8        32 1980
    9        18 1981
```

thank you in advance!

[Counting the number of elements with the values of x in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector)

[grouping data splitted by frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954153/grouping-data-splitted-by-frequencies)

[Aggregate data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261325/aggregate-data-in-r)

Comment: `with(yourdata, table(Year, Count))`... that kind of `Table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `table` function.  Something like:

```
with(yourdata, table(Year, Count))
```